# How to display last record from database in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

Write the query for displaying the last record in Entity Framework 5.0

Comment: I removed the redundancy from your "question" to demonstrate how ridiculous it is.

Answer (score 2):

Just sort in a descending order and take first.

```
var item = context.MyItems
                   .OrderByDescending(p => p.Date)
                   .FirstOrDefault();
```

ps. Since the order (first/last/nth) is defined over a context, I assumed you are referring to date.

Comment: use in database 1st??

Comment: Shouldn't differ either db or code first.